# Differences between sudo chroot and chroot

Tags: chroot, su

I want to test `chroot` on my Linux machine. I try the following command:

```
sudo chroot rootfs /bin/bash
```

After that, I can run some commands that defined in `rootfs`, e.g., ls, mkdir, ... However, if my command is:

```
chroot rootfs /bin/bash
```

I  cannot execute any basic commands. I  understand that  `sudo chroot` will run the `chroot` command under the `su` permission. However, when I run inside the new environment, I don't think `su` permission matters anymore. May I ask why.

Comment: Maybe because letting normal user use chroot over whole system is a really huge security risk?